# using javaMail to read shared mailbox

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am creating an interface capable of reading e-mails from a shared mailbox. I have already tried several different approaches I could find in stack over, but none worked. Examples:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
// Set manual Properties
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", "993");
props.put("mail.imaps.host", "outlook.office365.com");



try {
    /* Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

    store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "eduardo.david@hpe.com/APSDataExtract", "-myPassword-");
```

gives me the following result:

```
Exception while connecting to server: AUTHENTICATE failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:661)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.<init>(OutLookReader_imaps.java:39)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.main(OutLookReader_imaps.java:121)
```

If I try other codes, the result is the same:

```
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "hpe\\eduardo.david@hpe.com\\APSDataExtract", "-myPassword-");
```

Result:

```
Exception while connecting to server: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13;
  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:668)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.<init>(OutLookReader_imaps.java:39)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.main(OutLookReader_imaps.java:121)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:356)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.authplain(IMAPProtocol.java:603)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:736)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:642)
    ... 3 more
```

---

```
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "hpe\\eduardo.david\\APSDataExtract", "-myPassword-");
```

Result:

```
Inside MailReader()...
Exception while connecting to server: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13;
  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:668)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.<init>(OutLookReader_imaps.java:39)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.main(OutLookReader_imaps.java:121)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:356)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.authplain(IMAPProtocol.java:603)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:736)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:642)
```

### ... 3 more

```
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "hpe\\davidedu\\APSDataExtract", "-myPassword-");
```

Result:

```
Inside MailReader()...
Exception while connecting to server: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13;
  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:668)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.<init>(OutLookReader_imaps.java:39)
at t2.OutLookReader_imaps.main(OutLookReader_imaps.java:121)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:356)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.authplain(IMAPProtocol.java:603)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:736)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:642)
... 3 more
```

To access my own inbox, code works perfectly:

```
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "eduardo.david@hpe.com", "-myPassword-");
```

Inside MailReader()...
No. of Unread Messages : 580
No. of Messages : 849
No. of Deleted Messages : 2

Can anybody give to this java new programmer a simple solution in order to read a shared mailbox?

Comment: Fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), see these general [Hotmail/Outlook/Exchange instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#outlook) (change the host names appropriately), this [Exchange login entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#Exchange-login) and this page with [Outlook/Exchange specific issues](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Exchange), including links with more information about using shared mailboxes.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it adding this parameters:

```
sysProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
sysProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
```

I connected using:

```
 store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "name@abc.com\\sharedmailAlias", "password");
```

- My email: name@abc.com
- My shared email address:
  sharedmailAlias@abc.com

Comment: I had the same problem using camel mail consumer. I set the properties on camel url and it works! tnx