# Authentication Error with Java Mail delegate access

Tags: java, authentication, outlook, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use delegate mail access through javamail. I have configured the delegate access correctly on my system. But when I try to run the following code

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(true);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(mailServerIP, 993, "myAlias/DelegateAlias", "mypassword");

            System.out.println(store);
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
            for (Message message : messages) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
}
```

it shows me the following error

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
  at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:715)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
  at com.adecco.smpt.TestSSL.main(TestSSL.java:26)
```

If I try to access my mail box instead of shared mailbox everything works well. Is there a different syntax to access the SHARED MAILBOX in JAVA?
I am using the private mail server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javamail access to a shared mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951184/javamail-access-to-a-shared-mailbox)

Comment: If that possible duplicate does not help, look at the first comment under the following related Stack Overflow question: [using javaMail to read shared mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703065/using-javamail-to-read-shared-mailbox)

Comment: If none of the above help, tell us what kind of mail server you're using.